Geometrical name for the group of circles of decreasing diameter whose centers are displaced along a straight line, as observed in Doppler Effect
The wavefront received by a receiver from a moving source, or vice versa, is shown in the literature as circles of decreasing diameter whose centers are displaced along the direction of motion. I have spent some time looking for the proper geometrical name of this group of circles, but the nearest one I came across is "Doppler circles," as used by some artists (the figure they are referring to, strictly speaking, does not represent the group I am after). A Wikipedia article on the Doppler effect shows nice animations, but no name is mentioned for this group of circles.
The unique properties of these circles are as follows: (1) These circles have their centers fixed while they are expanding; (2) The spacing between the circumferences of these circles in any given angular direction is constant. (3) The first circle will always enclose all the other circles; the second one will always enclose all the circles except the first one, and the third will enclose all except the first and second, and it continues.
What is the correct geometrical name for this group of circles?

Please do not use random tags.

Probably not correct, but what about Apollonian circles?

Where did you find "Doppler circles" that weren't the kind of circle you're after?

@Blue, property (2) I mentioned still needs to be met.

@DavidK, For example. link. One can see six "Doppler circles" in that picture.

In that picture you have alternating black and white regions between circles, and the circles seem to all be tangent at one point, which is what you would get if the radiating object were traveling at exactly the speed of the waves. What about this ("Doppler effect")?

If you consider time as a third dimension, the circles become "level sets" of a "propagation cone" ; this cone will be more or less "slanted", according to the speed of propagation ; of course, projecting the cone gives one of the 3 figures in the answer by Narasimham.

I think the problem you'll have with most mathematical terms for these kinds of things is that the mathematical terms will tend to describe complete families of circles, at a continuum of distances along each radial rather than at equal or even discrete distances.

Too image-y for a comment ...

Like this?


yes, this animation shows the group of circles.

May be it has a name in Physics of propagation in fluids or even in light waves. But maximum amplitude reinforced wave is of more of interest in physics.The circles are crests/troughs in a fluidic medium.
If the velocity of the moving object is $c$ and natural velocity of wave propagation in still water/air is $v$ (assumed constant here)... for $R=v/c$ there are 3 cases
Case 1: R>1  Non-intersecting eccentric circular waves travel by Huygens principle with no envelope. The group of circles is a Doppler set? not sure. Perhaps we can call them expanding Huygen waves.
When $ c << v, R \to \infty $ we have concentric circles that you notice for a stone pebble sinks into placid water.
Case 2: Can be referred by means of the common wave front rather than the set of circles.  R=1 A vertical shock wave that travels with the object. In jet aircraft when R= M= mach number =1 airplanes break the sonic speed over the sea in order not to destroy frail civil structures by sonic boom.
Case 3: R<1 The travelling wave in the wake of moving object like a boat is usually seen from above on either side of boat hull.
In these two case the travelling wave is a singular solution of the set of circles.


It's conventional to use $c$ for the speed of wave propagation and $v$ for the moving object. With those labels, your description for $R=v/c<1$ makes sense. But in the figures you have it the other way around, $v$ for wave and $c$ for object.

I took conventional labels from Relativity theory..  $v$ velocity of particle/wave and $c$ the velocity of light, $v<c$. In the rightmost hand sketch  if angle $ 2 \alpha$ is between two red standing waves/sides then for angle  $ \alpha $ green side is on  opposite and another green hypotenuse is the adjacent side, making $ \sin \alpha=\dfrac{v}{c}<1. $

You wrote in the answer, "If the velocity of the moving object is $c$ and natural velocity of wave propagation in still water/air is $v$", opposite from the conventional labels. In the right-hand sketch, the velocity of the particle is the hypotenuse of the triangle and is in the denominator of $\sin\alpha$, where you put $c$ in your comment. And I just now noticed that both Case 1 and Case 3 state that $R < 1$.

Oh my bad. Thanks for pointing out the typo, is it ok now? Maybe I should  have included the concentric circles in the first of 4 cases.

Now the answer is self-consistent, although labeled oppositely from the conventions of relativity theory.

I understood labeling convention in Relativity as follows:  If rest mass  $m_{0}$ accelerates at $0<v<c$ ( $v$ particle velocity and $c$ velocity of light ) then
$ m= \frac{m_0}{\sqrt{1- \frac{v^2}{c^2}}} $ Ok?

Yes, that is the convention. Your labeling in the answer is opposite: you wrote $c$ where the convention is $v$ and you wrote $v$ where the convention is $c$. Your answer is mathematically sound, just labeled in an unusual way.

Labeled and shown $c>v$, hypotenuse longer than side. Seen in wakes formed from bow of boats and ships.

Yes, and this is possible only because the object (boat with speed $c$) is traveling faster than the propagated wave (with speed $v$). You've used $v$ for the wave velocity, whereas the convention in relativity is $c$.
